# Dynamic header navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

It’s kind of hard to explain in words, so I have uploaded a gif. My question is, does react-navigation offer this feature right of the box or do I have to do it on my own. If so, how could I accomplish this behavior? [image]